# AzureAD custom multi factor auth

Tags: azure-active-directory, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I've got a single page application that currently uses Azure AD B2C authentication to allow users to sign in, and then use the auth cookies to talk directly to internal services. There is now a requirement that we use two factor auth on top of the existing AD auth. We've already rolled our own 'second factor' auth, and we need to be able to integrate with that (I'd much rather use the built in MFA that Azure provides, but for this question assume that isn't an option).

Our issue is that we don't want to call our MFA service until the user has authenticated succesfully with AD - but of course, once they have, they are already authenticated, and it's too late.

When Azure AD hands back to us via the call back (we are using CookieAuthenticationEvents), is there any way to defer the access token being available until our own second factor auth step succeeds?

Comment: I think you'd have to use a Custom policy for that, to do the 2FA in B2C

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as juunas suggested, try to use custom polices which are designed primarily to address complex scenarios.

Reference:

[Custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom)

Comment: This is the route we went down - once auth'ed with AzureAD, the front-end JS challenges the user and validates their code with our MFA service that gives back an 'mfa token', and then we have a policy implemented on all non-public api endpoints that validates both the AzureAD JWT and also calls into our MFA service to validate the 'mfa token'. I've also strongly encouraged we use AzureAD for the whole process, but that decision is out of my hands.